# C# Blurring an Image

Tags: c#, image, blur

I am trying to blur an image in C# by going through all of the pixels of one image and then creating a new Bitmap with the color of the pixels in the original image divided by the pixel count to create an average color. When I run it, nothing happens. Here's the code:

```
private void blurToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Bitmap img = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Image);
        Bitmap blurPic = new Bitmap(img.Width, img.Height);

        Int32 avgR = 0, avgG = 0, avgB = 0;
        Int32 blurPixelCount = 0;

        for (int y = 0; y < img.Height; y++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < img.Width; x++)
            {
                Color pixel = img.GetPixel(x, y);
                avgR += pixel.R;
                avgG += pixel.G;
                avgB += pixel.B;

                blurPixelCount++;
            }
        }

        avgR = avgR / blurPixelCount;
        avgG = avgG / blurPixelCount;
        avgB = avgB / blurPixelCount;

        for (int y = 0; y < img.Height; y++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < img.Width; x++)
            {
                blurPic.SetPixel(x, y, Color.FromArgb(avgR, avgG, avgB));
            }
        }

        img = blurPic;
    }
```

Thanks!

Comment: Use a [BlurEffect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.effects.blureffect.aspx). Don't try to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: I believe your img object only exists in memory when this method is finished...don't you have to write it out to a new file?

Comment: @HighCore `BlureEffect` can only used on `DependencyObject` and is not usable in all situations.

Comment: @AmirOveisi in what situations do you have a `Visual` that is not a `DependencyObject`, please?

Comment: @HighCore if you don't use `WPF`/`SL` projects, then you don't have a `DependencyObject`! and here @user2816235 used a code with `EventArgs` for a button click not a `RoutedEventArgs`. so i assume that this is not a `WPF`/`SL` related question and it's about `WinFrom`. so no `DependencyObject` here.

Comment: @AmirOveisi that's right, if you're using a deprecated framework from the stone age like winforms, you won't be able to leverage the advantages of modern frameworks...

Comment: @HighCore yes you are absolutely right about that. but i was just talking about asked question. there is no doubt that `WPF` is far better than old `WinForm`.

Comment: You cannot edit a Bitmap, you first have to convert it to a writeablebitmap so that you may have access to all the pixels. In short, you first have to rasterize the bitmap first.

Comment: Let me write an answer for you.

Answer (score 1):

Use `pictureBox1.Image = blurPic;` at the end of your method.

Answer (score 0):

This is the easiest way to blur images in c# code but **N.B you have to wait for an image to load completely so that you can start working on it**

In short, we are going to use the ImageOpened event handler for your image. So we are going to use the WriteableBitmap class which has methods for blurring images and applying all sorts of effect to an image.

WriteableBitExtensions contain the GaussianBlur5x5 which is what we are going to use.

> This code assumes that you are getting the image from a url, so we first download the image to get the contents of the stream from the web. But if your image is local, then you can first convert it to a IRandomAccessStream and pass it as an argument.

```
double height = pictureBox1.ActualHeight;
        double width = pictureBox1.ActualWidth;

        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("image-url-goes-here");

        var webResponse = response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
        randomStream = webResponse.Result.AsRandomAccessStream();
        randomStream.Seek(0);


        wb = wb.Crop(50, 50, 400, 400);
        wb = wb.Resize(10,10 ,         WriteableBitmapExtensions.Interpolation.NearestNeighbor);
        wb = WriteableBitmapExtensions.Convolute(wb,WriteableBitmapExtensions.KernelGaussianBlur5x5);

        pictureBox1.Source= wb;
```